# Is the subfield of cyclotomic extension always has a cyclotomic minimal polynomial?

Tags: galois-theory

let $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension
Where $p$ is a prime number and  $\zeta_{p}$ is the pth roots of unity and  $G=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})$ be its Galois group we know that $|G|=\varphi(p)=p-1 $

$\Phi(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+....+x+1$ be the minimal of polynomial of the extension
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$
Let $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be an intermidiate field of the extension
$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$
S.t $[\mathbb{Q}:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]=m | p-1  $

I ask is the minimal polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ always have the form
$\Phi(x)=x^{m-1}+x^{m-2}+....+x+1$

Where $\alpha=a_{1}\zeta+a_{2}\zeta^{2}+...+a_{m}\zeta^{m}$
( the coefficients $a_{i} $ can be zero for some $i$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b\in\mathbb{C}$ be a primitive $5$-th root of $1$.

Note that $B=\mathbb{Q}(b)$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group cyclic of order $4$.

Thus the Galois group of $B$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a subgroup of index $2$, hence $B$ has a subfield $A$ such that $[A:\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

By the primitive element theorem, $A=\mathbb{Q}(a)$ for some $a\in B$.

Since $[A:\mathbb{Q}]=2$, the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $2$.

**Claim:**$\;$The minimal polynomial for $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not equal to $x^2+x+1$.

Suppose otherwise.

Then $a$ is a primitive cube root of $1$.

It follows that $ab$ is a primitive $15$-th root of $1$, so the the minimal polynomial for $ab\;$over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $\phi(15)=\phi(3)\phi(5)=8$.

But then $[\mathbb{Q}(ab):\mathbb{Q}]=8$, contradiction, since $ab\in B$ and $[B:\mathbb{Q}]=4$.

For a more explicit example, note that identically we have
$$
(2b^3+2b^2+1)^2=5
$$
so $B$ contains the subfield $A=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

But no element of $A$ is a primitive cube root of $1$, so no element of $A$ has $x^2+x+1$ for its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: so you mean that the above statment is always true for any cyclotomic extension ?

Comment: I gave an example of a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ for which there is a subfield which cannot be generated by an element whose minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ has the form you specified.

Comment: So does the minimal polynomial of a subfield of cyclic extension have a relation with $\Phi(x)$

Comment: My example shows that it need _not_ have the form you specified. In other words, it's a _counterexample_.

Comment: Minor nitpick:  It is true but not established in your Answer that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_{5})$ exists with degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$.  It might be clearer to simply exhibit such an $\alpha$.  For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Explicit_expressions_in_low_degrees), $\sqrt 5 \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_{5})$.

Comment: @hardmath: I edited to clarify.